# In-Place Quicksort in matlab

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, quicksort, in-place

I wrote a small quicksort implementation in matlab to sort some custom data. Because I am sorting a cell-array and I need the indexes of the sort-order and do not want to restructure the cell-array itself I need my own implementation (maybe there is one available that works, but I did not find it).

My current implementation works by partitioning into a `left` and `right` array and then passing these arrays to the recursive call. Because I do not know the size of `left` and and `right` I just grow them inside a loop which I know is horribly slow in matlab.

I know you can do an in place quicksort, but I was warned about never modifying the content of variables passed into a function, because call by reference is not implemented the way one would expect in matlab (or so I was told). Is this correct? Would an in-place quicksort work as expected in matlab or is there something I need to take care of? What other hints would you have for implementing this kind of thing?

Comment: What type of data is held in the cells?

Comment: The cells contain structs with several fields. I need to sort explicitly by a value stored in one of the fields. Hence I do a comparison of the fields and then sort a vector of numbers based on this comparison. Works fine right now, except for the speed, due to copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a sort on complex data in user M-code is probably going to be a loss in terms of performance due to the overhead of M-level operations compared to Matlab's builtins. Try to reframe the operation in terms of Matlab's existing vectorized functions.

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're sorting on a single-value key that's inside the structs in the cells. You can probably get a good speedup by extracting the sort key to a primitive numeric array and calling the builtin `sort` on that.

```
%// An example cell array of structs that I think looks like your input
c = num2cell(struct('foo',{'a','b','c','d'}, 'bar',{6 1 3 2}))
%// Let's say the "bar" field is what you want to sort on.
key = cellfun(@(s)s.bar, c) %// Extract the sort key using cellfun
[sortedKey,ix] = sort(key) %// Sort on just the key using fast numeric sort() builtin
sortedC = c(ix); %// ix is a reordering index in to c; apply the sort using a single indexing operation
reordering = cellfun(@(s)s.foo, sortedC)  %// for human readability of results
```

If you're sorting on multiple field values, extract all the m key values from the n cells to an n-by-m array, with columns in descending order of precedence, and use `sortrows` on it.

```
%// Multi-key sort
keyCols = {'bar','baz'};
key = NaN(numel(c), numel(keyCols));
for i = 1:numel(keyCols)
    keyCol = keyCols{i};
    key(:,i) = cellfun(@(s)s.(keyCol), c);
end
[sortedKey,ix] = sortrows(key);
sortedC = c(ix);
reordering = cellfun(@(s)s.foo, sortedC)
```

One of the keys to performance in Matlab is to get your data in primitive arrays, and use vectorized operations on those primitive arrays. Matlab code that looks like C++ STL code with algorithms and references to comparison functions and the like will often be slow; even if your code is good in O(n) complexity terms, the fixed cost of user-level M-code operations, especially on non-primitives, can be a killer.

Also, if your structs are homogeneous (that is, they all have the same set of fields), you can store them directly in a struct array instead of a cell array of structs, and it will be more compact. If you can do more extensive redesign, rearranging your data structures to be "planar-organized" - where you have a struct of arrays, reading across the ith elemnt of all the fields as a record, instead of an array of structs of scalar fields - could be a good efficiency win. Either of these reorganizations would make constructing the sort key array cheaper.

Comment: +1 good solution, here is a post discussing a similar approach: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/09/17/sorting-structure-arrays-based-on-fields/

Answer (score 4):

In this post, I only explain MATLAB function-calling convention, and am not discussing the quick-sort algorithm implementation.

When calling functions, MATLAB passes built-in data types [by-value](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96960-does-matlab-pass-parameters-using-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference), and any changes made to such arguments are not visible outside the function.

```
function y = myFunc(x)
    x = x .* 2;         %# pass-by-value, changes only visible inside function
    y = x;
end
```

This could be inefficient for large data especially if they are not modified inside the functions. Therefore MATLAB internally implements a [copy-on-write mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735841/initializing-a-ublas-vector-from-a-c-array/1735997#1735997): for example when a vector is copied, only some meta-data is copied, while the data itself is shared between the two copies of the vector. And it is only when one of them is modified, that the data is actually duplicated.

```
function y = myFunc(x)
    %# x was never changed, thus passed-by-reference avoiding making a copy
    y = x .* 2;
end
```

Note that for cell-arrays and structures, only the cells/fields modified are passed-by-value (this is because cells/fields are internally stored separately), which makes copying more efficient for such data structures. For more information, read this [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/).

In addition, versions R2007 and upward (I think) detects [in-place operations](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/) on data and optimizes such cases.

```
function x = myFunc(x)
    x = x.*2;
end
```

Obviously when calling such function, the LHS must be the same as the RHS (`x = myFunc(x);`). Also in order to take advantage of this optimization, in-place functions must be called from inside another function.

In MEX-functions, although it is possible to change input variables without making copies, it is not officially supported and might yield unexpected results...

For [user-defined types](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) (OOP), MATLAB introduced the [concept](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/copying-objects.html) of [value object vs. handle object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) supporting [reference semantics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-objects.html#btm3mnr).

Comment: Thanks for the help. This went a long way to clarify why I and others were having this problem and unexpected behavior with passed variables. However I still am not quite sure how to achieve the speed up with quicksort. The algorithm (even in place) is clear and I have implemented it several times already in other languages. I am still using matlab 2006, so I might have to switch to a more recent version in order to be able to use the tricks you gave in the links.

Comment: @LiKao: using the built-in `SORT` function as @AndrewJanke has shown is going to be faster in most cases. If you truly want to squeeze out every bit of performance, consider using C\C++ in a MEX-file, where you can call the standard `qsort()` or `std::sort` functions, or even implement your own custom sort function (especially if you have further knowledge about your data that you can take advantage of). Of course you will have to use the MEX API to access the cellarrays/structure content...

Comment: @Amro: Simply switching to `qsort` or `std::sort` in MEX is probably going to be a loss. Surprisingly, Matlab's `sort` is faster out of the box in many cases, probably mostly because it's multithreaded and C/C++ standard sorts are single-threaded. E.g. on my quad core box, Matlab `sort` benchmarks 4x faster than a simple MEX `qsort` on primitives. Also, predicates in C sorts would pay the expensive cell/structure/object access cost on the `O(n log n)` comparisons inside the sort, instead of the `O(n)` key extractions up front. It'd have to be pretty clever MEX to be a win.

Comment: `std::sort` looks a lot faster than `qsort` (inlining and optimizations based on static type info, probably); still slower than Matlab `sort` on my quad-core, but could be a win on dual or single cores, on primitives.

Comment: @AndrewJanke: I completely agree with you (just [remember](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN) that multi-threaded SORT only kicks in for double arrays with >40k elements). Now I know that the sorting problem has been largely "solved", yet suppose we knew that the data was semi-sorted for example, then it could be beneficial to use another sorting algorithm that might take advantage of this fact, which would be faster than the one designed for the average case.

Comment: Finally you can write multi-threaded code in MEX files too, as long as you keep all uses of the MEX API in the main thread only (as MEX functions are not thread-safe), but its probably too much trouble as you can imagine.